# Mocking system events using MOQ

Tags: c#, mocking, moq, systemevent

Is there a way to mock system events in C# such as `SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged` and artificially raise them in a MOQ setup?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart#Events

Comment: The event is not owned by the mocked type though. The event I need to mock is part of SystemEvents.

Comment: You could create an interface (that can be mocked) which exposes SystemEvents to you. Very similar to what is done by having an "IDateTimeService" mock DateTime.Now.

Answer (score 3):

A litte bit late, but here is an example for the implementation with an interface in front of SystemEvent Matt mentioned:

Interface:

```
public interface ISystemEvents
{
    event PowerModeChangedEventHandler PowerModeChanged;
}
```

Adapter class:

```
public class SystemEventsAdapter : ISystemEvents
{
    public event PowerModeChangedEventHandler PowerModeChanged;
}
```

Your registration on the event:

```
public class TestClass {

   private readonly ITestService _testService;

   public TestClass(ISystemEvents systemEvents, ITestService testService) {
      _testService = testService;
      systemEvents.PowerModeChanged += OnPowerModeChanged;
   }

   private void OnPowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      if (e.Mode == PowerModes.Resume)
      {
          _testService.DoStuff();
      }
   }
}
```

Test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestClassTests
{
     private TestClass _cut;

     private Mock<ISystemEvents> _systemEventsMock;         
     private Mock<ITestService> _testServiceMock;

     [SetUp]
     public void SetUp()
     {
         _systemEventsMock = new Mock<ISystemEvents>();
         _testServiceMock = new Mock<ITestService>();

         _cut = new TestClass(
            _systemEventsMock.Object,
            _testServiceMock.Object
         );
     }

     [TestFixture]
     public class OnPowerModeChanged : TestClassTests
     {
         [Test]
         public void When_PowerMode_Resume_Should_Call_TestService_DoStuff()
         {
             _systemEventsMock.Raise(m => m.PowerModeChanged += null, new PowerModeChangedEventArgs(PowerModes.Resume));

             _testServiceMock.Verify(m => m.DoStuff(), Times.Once);
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

No, not directly.

I see two ways to achieve this :

1. By Implementing an interface in front of the systemEvent
2. By using a detouring framework such as [Moles Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798308.aspx) or the [Microsoft Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx)